# Lost hundreds of files in a folder in a split second

Tags: windows-7

I was trying to delete a subfolder in a folder and noticed I lost all the files and subfolders in the folder in a split second. This is really unusual because it happened too fast. It would have taken at least 30 seconds (due to the number of files and folders) if I wanted a normal delete. I think I saw a flicker too.  The files were not in the recycle bin. I rebooted and the files were not there. Then I ran a portable file recovery app from a USB drive and it found NO deleted files in the whole drive! I mean not in any other folders either. Another weird thing.

I am guessing some corruption happened maybe in the file system or MFT but Windows and apps seem to be running fine. But the odd thing there are no traces of deleted files anywhere.
(I don't have a backup but then the deleted files were mostly downloads over 2 years and can be replaced)

Any ideas of what could have happened?

Comment: Run a smart tool - see if the hard drive is dying

Comment: It's a few months old SSD.

Comment: So you didn't run a smart tool and because the drive is new it must therefore be without faults? Up to you! I also suggest a virus scan and malware scan

Comment: Which smart tool?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like the folder and subfolders got moved instead of deleted because of the speed the deleted. If you know the name of one of the files try doing a search of the drive for it.

Comment: It wasn't that. I searched and didn't find anything. If it were a move, the whole folder would have moved instead of just the contents.